# Getting an error 160 from PayPal PayFlow using layout C

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, payflowlink

I'm pulling my hair out trying to figure out why I can't seem to get a secure token from PayPal PayFlow Advanced in the sandbox.

Instead of getting parameter type results, I'm getting an html page with the error:

```
Some required information is missing or incorrect. Please correct the fields below and try again.
Error: Your transaction can no longer be processed. Please return to the merchant's web site or contact the merchant. Error: 160
```

I've followed several code examples and ready through the PayPal PayFlow guide PDF. I've been searching for several days and haven't been able to find much of anything regarding the error 160 other than one post which said curl was disabled on his server. It's enabled on my server. I also saw a post (from Dec. 2012) about having some of the parameters in a particular order in the request parameters.

I've tried the suggestions I found, but nothing seems to change the results.

Why am I getting an html page instead of the results?

URL: `https://pilot-payflowlink.paypal.com`

Post Fields: `TRXTYPE=S&PARTNER=PayPal&VENDOR=xxxx&USER=xxxx&PWD=xxxx&INVNUM=xxxxxx&AMT=22.34&CREATESECURETOKEN=Y&SECURETOKENID=52895d03afc761.99691257`

Curl Options:

```
$options = array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_HEADER         => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_VERBOSE        => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => FALSE,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => FALSE,
    CURLOPT_POST           => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => $info
);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Sloan

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but there are always issues when doing a PayPal integration.  Probably the first thing to do is  be sure you're using the correct version of the API (verify the version of the API in the doc you're working off).  It's probably a good idea to set the API version in your request too.

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to [How do I get the Security Token for PayPal Payments Advanced gateway integration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16988021/how-do-i-get-the-security-token-for-paypal-payments-advanced-gateway-integration/20532240#20532240)

I couldn't get a token from from https://pilot-payflowlink.paypal.com but https://pilot-payflowpro.paypal.com seems to work just fine. That's also indicated by a careful reading of the documentation at https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/payflow/gs_ppa_hosted_pages/
(but it's hardly obvious).